# Is it possible to call a route in an external js file in Slim

Tags: javascript, routes, slim

In my twig file I am calling a route to my ajax like so

```
var fund = $('#fund');

        //this will call php to populate fund drop-down
        $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path_for('myfundrequest') }}",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
        var len = response.length;

        fund.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var fundNum = response[i][0];
        var fundName = response[i][1];

        fund.append("<option value='" + fundNum + "'>" + fundNum + ' -- ' + fundName + "</option>");
        }
        fund.prepend("<option value=''>- Select A Fund -</option>").val('');
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("getFund: " + error);
        });
        });
```

And here is my routing

```
$app->get('/fundrequest', 'PoEntryController:funds')->setName('myfundrequest');
```

My question is, if I create an external js file in my public folder
is it possible to make this work `url: "{{ path_for('myfundrequest') }}` in the external file?

Comment: And it will not be processed by Slim, right? You just have some file you want to run outside of Slim? Is it another PHP file? Are you using Apache type server?

Comment: Well the url is calling a function that is in a controller. and yes apache.

Comment: If you don't want to have Slim process the url, and instead want to directly run the file in the URL, then you can set up .htaccess so that your URLs to existing files don't get processed by Slim. If that's something you are interested in, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I have around 1000 lines of js. Should I leave it in my twig file, which is working now, or move it to a an external js file?

Comment: I would move it out to a JS file. I would add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to the .htaccess. Look at see how this is used with Slim or other frameworks.

Comment: Like I said I have the ajax in a controller as a function. I know I can't call a function from ajax. Would the .htaccess treat the function call like a php file?

Comment: No. Ajax is for making HTTP requests. You can pass in POST data, do GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc. If you need something done on the server, that's why you use ajax. If you don't need something done on the server, but just want to use an external JS, then just use a script tag with a src attribute.

Comment: aha. That's where my problem is. I am getting data from the server via ajax.

Comment: You're doing this because you don't want to hardcode this route's address in your js file? I mean you don't want your js file to include `url: "/fundrequest"` in the `$.ajax` call?

Comment: if I "hard code" my route it will only point to the controller and not the function inside the controller correct?

Comment: @Nima I didn't understand routes until I tried hard coding. It Worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*No, its not possible on a plain JavaScript file, but*

I can think of two options:

1. Add the JavaScript file as twig file and then later render it with twig on a route.

   ```
   $app->get('/data/myScripts.js', 'ScriptProvider:myScript');

   class ScriptProvider {
       public function myScript($req, $res) {
           return $this->view->render($res, 'data/myScript.js.twig');
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the urls as global variables maybe on an global object

   *index.twig*

   ```
   <!-- [..] -->
   <script>
      Url = {
          myfundrequest: "{{ path_for('myfundrequest') }}"
      };
   </script>
   ```

   and then later use `Url.myfundrequest` as the url in JavaScript

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: Url.myfundrequest,
       ..
   ```

The second option would be more performant as the twig engine doesn't need to run.

Comment: I tried the second method and got this error ```%7B%7B%20path_for('myvendorrequest')%20%7D%7D```

Comment: @moe where do you get an error, also thats not really an error there should be some message to it.

Comment: I see it in my console. This is the response ```{"message":"Not found"}```

Comment: @moe probably the response of your route?

Comment: what is the advantage of doing the second over hard coding the routes the way @Nima suggested?

Comment: @moe when the url of the route changes, all still does work, otherwise you would need to change the hardcoded strings in your javascript files.